# Как динамически в программе менять background-image в QTableWidget?

Tags: python, background, qtablewidget, background-image

Есть однострочная таблица, могу в ней поставить фон с помощью стилей.

```
QTableWidget.setStyleSheet('background-image: url(tmp_qpix.png)')
```

Но мне нужно вместо **tmp_qpix.png** использовать **Qpixmap**, **QImage** или **PIL Image**, что-бы не обращаться к файлу на диске и иметь возможность програмно видоизменять картинку. После чего делать её фоновым изображением **всей таблицы** (или строки).
Это возможно реализовать?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick Тут воспроизводить в примере нечего. Это именно вопрос, существуют какие либо способы вставить в background один из вариантов (Qpixmap, QImage или PIL Image) или не существуют.